MariaDB shutdown unexpectedly in XAMPP but log does not show errors
When I start MariaDB on XAMPP, it shut down unexpectedly. But when I check the log error, it shows as below:
2024-06-21 11:01:02 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.32-MariaDB source revision c4143f909528e3fab0677a28631d10389354c491 as process 12900
2024-06-21 11:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2024-06-21 11:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2024-06-21 11:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.3
2024-06-21 11:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-06-21 11:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2024-06-21 11:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 64M, instances = 1, chunk size = 64M
2024-06-21 11:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-06-21 11:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2024-06-21 11:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2024-06-21 11:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-06-21 11:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2024-06-21 11:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2024-06-21 11:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.32 started; log sequence number 152406619; transaction id 27647
2024-06-21 11:01:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2024-06-21 11:01:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-06-21 11:01:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

It does not show any errors; therefore, I have no clue to fix it.
Here are what I tried, but nothing works:

Check if port 3306 is used anywhere by command ```netstat -ano | findstr :3306
Increase innodb_buffer_pool_size to 64MB
Increase max_execute_time to 600

Sometime, when I tried to click Start in XAMPP many times, it is able to start MariaDB on port 3306. But then I go to phpMyAdmin, it load like forever. The funny thing is that yesterday I was still able to start MariaDB. But today I can't.
Please help me with this issue. Thank you very much.

Has the server enough space? Not sure if could be an issue, but did you try to run it as administrator? Could one of the databases be corrupted? Maybe through a improper unexpected shutdown. Which version of XAMPP/PHP/MySQL are you running?

It's probably an unpopular opinion, but IMHO, the best approach is to set up your LAMP server using OS package managers chocolatey for Windows and brew for Mac. If you're developing cross-platform, working on Windows, and deploying to Linux, then I would actually recommend you use WSL to virtualize since it's free.

You have mariadb and not mysql (check out the log you copied into the question...)

The problem is that we can't magically tell you why mariadb is not starting on your computer. Based on the logs, mariadb is running. Perhaps the issue us with phpmyadmin or other parts of your stack. We really can't tell.
